# Does caulk or spackle make more sense here?

Tags: caulk, joints, spackling-paste

[image: close-up of joints to be filled]

Notwithstanding my user name :), I'd welcome some advice on whether caulk or spackle would be better to fill these gaps and produce a uniform surface. The left side is a heavily painted metal window frame. The right is a laminate wardrobe, primed. The window frame has edges (not pictured) that prevent the wardrobe from butting up against it, so I've added a strip of solid wood in between, also primed. (The ruler is for scale and also shows the depth of the left-hand gap; both gaps run about 60" vertically.)

I want to end up with a uniform, smooth surface across both gaps that will produce a crisp line when I paint the wardrobe & filler a color while leaving the window frame white.

Caulk and spackle each have advantages. OOH, caulk would flex if the different materials moved in different ways. OTOH, my friend spackle seems like it would produce a smoother surface, especially since caulk and I are only recent acquaintances.

I'm happy to provide more details if needed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, I’d caulk between the window frame and the filler and spackle the wood to wood joint.

The caulk at the window frame will have a little bit of give with dissimilar materials.

The spackle at the wood will allow a flat joint. It may, in time, crack. If flatness wasn’t a goal, I’d caulk that as well.